# How to append user data to rest URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, url

I'm trying to append a user's phone number to the end of a RESTful URL:

```
var phnNum = 999999999;           
$.ajax({           
    url: 'http://localhost:8087/sports/users/'+'phnNum',
    dataType: 'application/json',       
    type: 'GET'
})
```

I'm trying to call

```
http://localhost:8087/sports/user/9999999
```

but the above code is calling

```
http://localhost:8087/sports/users/phnNum
```

Instead of appending the phone number value it is appending variable name phnNum. How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to append `phnNum` variable without single quote and **remove** single quote after and before from `phnNum`.

```
url: 'http://localhost:8087/sports/users/'+phnNum,
```

Comment: Probably best to leave out the port and just use `"/sports/users/" + phnNum`

Answer (score 1):

Just do, don't use `' ... '`

```
url: 'http://localhost:8087/sports/users/'+phnNum,
```

And if they are on same domain and port `http://localhost:8087/` then use

```
url: '/sports/users/'+phnNum,
```

Comment: Thanks Ashok, I am the one who downvoted just out of curiosity.

Comment: no, they are not in same domain. my rest on 8087.  my local tomcat on 8080 port.

Comment: Then you should be using the first one. And If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

var phnNum = 999999999;
url: 'http://localhost:8087/sports/users/'+phnNum,